# Output gantt chart and output each process total waiting time

Tags: java, gantt-chart, round-robin

I have tried lots of things to output a gantt chart of this round Robing CPU scheduling program but i am unable to do so. Being at it for quite a while and i need help figuring it out. I also need to output the total waiting time of each process in the table of processes but i can't get it to work. I am probably not doing it in order.

Code is below if anyone could take a look at it and guide me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

the program is quite big so i have shared a dropbox link here to make it easier to download and run the program.

[code here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cwhvx090dfnit5z/AACzKeJVJ9U-rjBrWFb7zsY3a?dl=0)

```
public class Display {

/**
 * Starts the simulation
 */
/**
 * Display Processes processing sequence
 * @param time Timing when process is in CPU
 * @param message Process Name
 */
public static void logTime(int time, String message) {
    RoundRobin.ps.printf(" | " + message);

}
/**
 * Display CPU Scheduling results
 * @param simulation Display Process table and Processes Execution Sequence
 */
public static void simulation() {

    // Before starting the simulation, print first the generated processes
    Iterator<Process> it = RoundRobin.processes.iterator();

    RoundRobin.ps.println("--------------+---------------+--------------");         
    RoundRobin.ps.println("ROUND ROBIN SIMULATION RESULT");
    RoundRobin.ps.println("--------------+---------------+--------------"); 
    RoundRobin.ps.println("TIME QUANTUM: " + RoundRobin.timeQuantum);
    RoundRobin.ps.println("--------------+---------------+--------------"); 
    RoundRobin.ps.printf("%27s%n", "PROCESSES");
    RoundRobin.ps.println("--------------+---------------+--------------");     
    RoundRobin.ps.println("Process Name  | Arrival Time | Burst Time | Waiting Time");

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Process process = it.next();
        RoundRobin.ps.format("%-16s%-15d%-16s%n", process.getName(), process.getArrivalTime(), process.getBurstTime());
    }
    RoundRobin.ps.println("--------------+---------------+--------------"); 
    RoundRobin.ps.println();

    CPU cpu = new CPU();
    Queue<Process> waitingQueue = new LinkedList<Process>();

    while(true) {
        // check if there are processes that has arrived and add them to the waiting queue
        LinkedList<Process> arrivedProcesses = RoundRobin.getArrivedProcessed(cpu.getTime());

        it = arrivedProcesses.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
            waitingQueue.add(it.next());

        // check if the CPU is busy
        if(!cpu.isProcessing()) {
            // if the CPU is not busy then get one of the process in the waiting queue to be processed
            if(!waitingQueue.isEmpty())
                cpu.acceptProcess(waitingQueue.poll());
            else
                // if the waiting queue is empty then that means that the CPU is idle
                logTime(cpu.getTime(), "IDLE");
        }

        // continue the process of the CPU
        if(cpu.isProcessing()) {
            cpu.doProcess();
            logTime(cpu.getTime(), cpu.getProcess().getName());

            // check if the CPU has finished the process to put the next process right away for processing
            if(cpu.hasFinishedProcess()) {
                RoundRobin.finishedProcesses.add(cpu.getProcess());

                cpu.clearProcess();

                if(!waitingQueue.isEmpty())
                    cpu.acceptProcess(waitingQueue.poll());
            } else {
                // check for context switching
                Process process = cpu.getProcess();

                if(process.getProcessedBurstTime() % RoundRobin.timeQuantum == 0) {
                    // do context switch by removing the current process and putting it back to the queue
                    cpu.clearProcess();
                    RoundRobin.ps.println();
                    // ps.print(" |-| ");
                    waitingQueue.add(process);

                    // add the next process if there is
                    if(!waitingQueue.isEmpty())
                        cpu.acceptProcess(waitingQueue.poll());
                }
            }
        }

        // check if everything is finished
        if(waitingQueue.isEmpty() && !cpu.isProcessing() && RoundRobin.processes.isEmpty())
            break;

        cpu.incrementTime();
        RoundRobin.increaseWaitingTimeToWaitingProcesses(waitingQueue);
    }

    RoundRobin.ps.println();
    RoundRobin.ps.println();
    RoundRobin.ps.println("Average Waiting Time: \t\t" +     RoundRobin.getAverageWaitingTime());
    RoundRobin.ps.println("Average Turn Around Time: \t" + RoundRobin.getAverateTurnAroundTime());
    RoundRobin.ps.printf("%-1s%.2f%1s%n","Utilization Rate: \t\t", RoundRobin.getUtilizationRate(cpu), "%");
    RoundRobin.ps.printf("%-1s%.2f%1s%n", "Throughput: \t\t\t", RoundRobin.getThroughput(cpu), "%");
    RoundRobin.ps.println();
    RoundRobin.ps.flush();
}
```

}

Output so for.

```
--------------+---------------+--------------
ROUND ROBIN SIMULATION RESULT
--------------+---------------+--------------
TIME QUANTUM: 5
--------------+---------------+--------------
              PROCESSES
--------------+---------------+--------------
Process Name  | Arrival Time  | Burst Time | Waiting Time
P1              0              5               
P2              5              20              
P3              6              12              
P4              8              14              
P5              10             3               
--------------+---------------+--------------
//each new line represents a context switch

 | P1 | P1 | P1 | P1 | P1 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P2
 | P3 | P3 | P3 | P3 | P3
 | P4 | P4 | P4 | P4 | P4
 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P2
 | P5 | P5 | P5 | P3 | P3 | P3 | P3 | P3
 | P4 | P4 | P4 | P4 | P4
 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P2
 | P3 | P3 | P4 | P4 | P4 | P4 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P2 | P295


Average Waiting Time:       95.0
Average Turn Around Time:   29.4
Utilization Rate:       101.89%
Throughput:             9.43%
```

Expected Chart output of processes followed processed time of each process
[image: Expected Chart output of processes followed processed time of each process]

Comment: can you add an example of what your expected output is (what you want to see) so that we have an idea of how it compares to what you're currently getting?